# C++ compilation for iPhone (STL issue?)

Tags: c++, iphone, xcode, stl, compilation

I am trying to compile some C++ code as a static library to use on the iPhone. If I compile things for the simulator (i386 architecture), everything compiles just peachy, but when I switch the architecture to arm, I get all these include errors, seemingly within the iPhone SDK STL headers. Any idea what's going on?

First of the errors:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:45:0 Bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory in 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string
```

Comment: This is using the iPhone 3.2 SDK Beta btw. If I choose the target as Device 3.2, it seems to work, but all lesser OS versions give me these errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv6-apple-darwin9/` as the include path.

Also, please file a bug to Apple.

Comment: adding this path will only fix device builds.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this bug for all SDK versions, add

```
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/armv6-apple-darwin9
```

to the "Header Search Paths" build setting (the architecture shouldn't matter; this still works for the simulator for me).

Answer (score 0):

There are no armv6-apple-darwin9 subdirectory